# Getting Unknown object type when trying to set null using TYPES.NULL

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I am trying to execute a update statement using JDBC and I am trying to set null values like below.

```
updateStmt.setNull(j + 1, Types.NULL);
```

But when ever this statement gets executed I get the below error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown object type
at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:355)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.createInstanceFromClassName(IfxValue.java:403)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.makeInstanceFromIfxType(IfxValue.java:635)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.makeInstanceFromIfxType(IfxValue.java:610)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxValue.makeInstance(IfxValue.java:390)
at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.setNull(IfxPreparedStatement.java:396)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all databases have a dedicated `NULL` data type, and it seems Informix is one of them.

For best portability use the actual type of the column with a `null` value.

For example (assuming the column type is `VARCHAR`, adjust as needed):

```
updateStmt.setString(j + 1, null);
```

Or:

```
updateStmt.setNull(j + 1, Types.VARCHAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `Types.NULL`.  Instead use the Type of the column you want to insert the null into.